# jQuery change form action based on selector value

Tags: jquery, html

Here's the situation.  I've got a form containing a select box and a search field.  I'm needing the option selected in the select box to determine the action of the search field.  I've seen multiple posts like this, but here's where I think my post is a little bit different: my form actions are URLs that need to be able to accept the input of the search field (and the URLs are very picky for each website about what is tagged on as a search query).  For example,

The user selects "Digikey" from the select box, the form action changes to `https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=`.  The search field entry is `C0603C0G1H180J030BA`.  I need this entry to be tacked on to a specific part of the URL query so that it aligns with the corresponding url were I just to go to www.digikey.com and enter that same search into their site's search (I suggest whoever reads this visit this website, search the entry I have provided and observe the url to get a better idea of what I'm talking about).

I have attempted a solution using jQuery.

**EDIT** The URL I receive (for Digikey) is:

`https://www.digikey.com/products/en?q=C0603C0G1H180J030BA`

instead of what it needs to be:

`https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keyword=C0603C0G1H180J030BA`

**HTML**

```
 <form class="form-inline" data-toggle="#octopart" action="http://octopart.com/search" style="padding-top: 10px;">
         <div class="input-group mb-3" style="width: 50%;">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                 <select class="custom-select" id="searchEngine">
                     <option value='octopart'>OctoPart</a></option>
                     <option value='digikey'>DigiKey</a></option>
                     <option value='mouser'>Mouser</a></option>
                     <option value='generalsearch'>General Search</a></option>
                 </select>
             </div>    
             <input class="form-control" type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search part ..." name="search" style="width: 200px">
             <div class="input-group-append">
                 <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" data_target="#octopart" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
             </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#searchEngine').change(function(){
        var selectedEngine = $(this).val();
        if (selectedEngine == "octopart") {
            $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "www.octopart.com/search");
            } else if (selectedEngine == "digikey") {
            $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=" + $(this).closest("form").val());
            } else if (selectedEngine == "mouser") {
            $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/");
            } else {
            $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "www.google.com/search");
            }
});
```

Comment: We'll need to know exactly what the problem you're having with your code is. "I have been unable to place the search entry in just the right place" is a bit vague.

Comment: See my edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to submit that form set `method` as `'GET'` and change the `name` of the fields you want in the query params to match the expected params at endpoint

Working example for digikey only

```js
var resources = {
  digikey: {
    url: 'https://www.digikey.com/products/en',
    query: 'keywords'
  },
  // won't open in iframe in demo
  /* octopart:{
     url:'https://octopart.com/search',
     query:'q'
   }*/

};

var $sInput = $('#search-input');

$('form').submit(function() {
  var params = resources[$('#searchEngine').val()];
  this.action = params.url;
  $sInput.attr('name', params.query);
});
```

```css
iframe {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="GET" target="my-iframe">

  <select id="searchEngine">
    <option value='octopart'>OctoPart</option>
    <option value='digikey' selected>DigiKey</option>
    <option value='mouser'>Mouser</option>
    <option value='generalsearch'>General Search</option>
  </select>

  <input id="search-input" placeholder="Search part ..." value="audio">

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>


<iframe id="my-iframe" name="my-iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Very clever solution.  I've been looking for a way to independently declare the url and query, as that seemed to be the root of the issue.  Many thanks sir, upvoted!

Comment: Up to you to make sure everything is valid before submitting but basics are fairly straightforward

Comment: Cool. Is really the only way to make it work using form submit simply because that's how forms work. Alternative would be use `window.open` and could use `URL API to build the url

Answer (score 0):

Here you have given two names to the input which is not a best practice

name="q" and name="search"

I changed from

`$(this).closest("form").val()`

to

```
$(this).closest(":input[name=q]").val()


$(this).closest("form").submit(function() {
            var selectedEngine = $("#searchEngine").val();
            if (selectedEngine == "octopart") {
                $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "www.octopart.com/search");
                } else if (selectedEngine == "digikey") {
                $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=" + $(this).closest(":input[name=q]").val());
                } else if (selectedEngine == "mouser") {
                $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/");
                } else {
                $(this).closest("form").attr("action", "www.google.com/search");
                }
    });
```

Comment: I hadn't noticed that I had two names, thanks for the spot.  I removed `name="search"`, however I'm still receiving the same result as before (see my edit please)